# Where should I maintain the socket connection in android app

Tags: android, websocket

I have an Android app that needs to establish a socket connection when it comes to the foreground. This connection is intended for receiving updates and writing them to a local database. Here are my requirements:

- Connection Duration: The connection should automatically disconnect after approximately 30 seconds in the background.
- No Persistent Notification: I cannot use a foreground service because a persistent notification is not suitable for my use case.

What is the recommended way of achieving the same.

Comment: You do not need a service if your socket connection is only needed in the foreground. You can use an ordinary repository or similar singleton to manage the connection and use `ProcessLifecycleOwner` to determine when to begin the 30-second countdown.

Comment: I question whether the foreground only part is actually important/wanted.  Rather than using a socket at all, you'd probably be better off with push messages and a BroadcastReceiver to listen to them and write to the db.

Comment: @GabeSechan What do you mean by foreground only part being important? Do you mean it should be fine getting push messages even in the background and not use socket at all?

Comment: Yes.  I'd say just using push messaging is generally how these things are written.